# Get content from web page

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm trying to get one value from my web page. When I execute first time it returns null, but if I execute another time returns correct value...

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://localhost/app/check.aspx";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_WebView loadRequest:urlRequest];
NSString *html = [_WebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.getElementById('Contador').textContent"];
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"Avisos Activos"
                                               message:html
                                              delegate: self
                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                     otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];

[alert setTag:1];
[alert show];
```

Comment: `loadRequest` *"Connects to a given URL by initiating an asynchronous client request."* - that means your javascript is evaluated on an invalid context where the request has not finished yet, the DOM has not been populated yet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a delegate the the web view and wait for the callback which tells you the page load has finished, the you can run your JavaScript.

Ideally you'd have a web service to get the data instead...

Comment: Thank's. I will try. Its my first app on ios